# How can I Refresh JSON file to reload configs/other json files for my Discord JS bot

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm currently using "`require(./file.json)`" because I can't get anything else to work.
So I want to be able to reload config file so I can disable / enable some commands in my bot without having to restart it.
Any Help or Suggestion will be appreciated!

If JSON doesn't work then any other file that can be used as a "config/db" is fine!

Thank you!

Comment: Could you provide us with some of the code you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read a JSON file, you need to use the built-in `fs` module.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const myFile = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('file.json'));
//edit myFile however you want
fs.writeFileSync('file.json', JSON.stringify(myFile, null, 4));
```

Comment: It works, but how can I get it to Refresh whenI use a command that uses "file.json"

Comment: You can read the file and assign its content again, by doing `const myFile = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('file.json'));` (the second line) again. Remember to do this before every time you want to change anything in the file.

Answer (score 0):

use `fs` to read file contents, instead of `include` or `require`, When you make include, it will read once in run-time only.

Also you can use `require` inside functions, which makes read in every function call. This is not pretty (In my opinion), But it works.